# JDownloader Installation gone wrong?

Tags: software-installation

so right off the bat I want to apologize for my inexperience. I usually like figuring stuff out myself rather than being a nuisance to other people. But this is my first day using Ubuntu, I am not really great with computers in general and I just can not seem to manage.

So I tried to install Jdownloader.
I am pretty sure I did something wrong as, well, it didn't work.
So basically I followed the instructions of [Wikihow](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Jdownloader-on-Ubuntu) (adorable, right?) and got to Step 4 but after entering `sudo apt-get install JDownloader` instead of getting something that lets me type `Y` or `N` (Step 5), I get

```
E: Unable to locate package JDownloader
```

If anyone could help somehow and would take the time for a stupid beginner's mistake, that'd really be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must know that in the linux world almost everything is **case-sensitive**.

So *JDownloader* is not the same as *jdownloader* as outlined in that tutorial.

The correct command is `sudo apt-get install jdownloader`.